# Running a function when the content of yui rte is changed

Tags: yui, onchange, rich-text-editor

I'm currently using the Rich Text Editor from the YUI framework. But I don't know how I can run a function when the content of the editor has changed. Want to do this to give the user a message if they leave the site and there is unsaved changes.

Any idea anyone? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the ['afterNodeChange'](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html#event_afterNodeChange) event.

Study the API for the Events. It is there that you will find the answers that you seek :-)

Comment: Really don't understand to much about the yui docs, but think i solved it some kind of an ugly way with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

editorKeyPress event gives almost all functionality of onchange() html event.